# How to get number of rows in datatable after ajax load

Tags: ajax, datatable

```
"ajax": {

        "url": "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Home?value=getreqs5",
        "data": function ( json,callback) {
            var oTable = $('#fifth').dataTable();

            // Get the length
            var count=oTable.fnGetData().length;
         return json;
        }
      }
```

Ajax data is successfully loaded in datatable.But the number of rows showing zero. How can i get number of rows in datatable after ajax return data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using datatables 1.10 you can get the total rows number with

```
"ajax": {
     "url" : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Home?value=getreqs5",
     "dataSrc": function(res){
         var count = res.data.length;
         alert(count);

         return res.data;
     }
}
```

With the `dataSrc` you can get the ajax success callback. In this callback you can count the objects number than your Ajax returns.

If you want to know how many rows you have in all your Datatable including all rows in all pages you can do this in your datatables parameter but out your ajax parameter :

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json){ 
     var info = this.api().page.info();
     alert('Total records', info.recordsTotal);
 }
```

Comment: how to get count after ajax load

Comment: I updated my code. You can try this with the dataSrc parameter.

Comment: This will returns you only the ajax rows number. Not the total of rows in your datatable for each page.

Comment: In my case, ajax rows number also helpfull...i accepted your answer

Comment: Excellent solution

Comment: I'm using version JQuery DataTables 1.10.11 and I had to remove the `data` property in the first part of your solution. For instance, you have `var count = res.data.length`... I had to make it `var count = res.length` and return `res` instead of `res.data`.  Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 4):

Just adding for all people looking for how to get to the api in other usecases:

```
var table = $("#myTable").dataTable();   
table.on('draw', function (data) {
    console.log(table.page.info().recordsDisplay);
});
```